# How do I fix connection problem in update sources of ubuntu 15.04 vivid?

Tags: package-management, updates, 15.04

I'm trying to update my system with the habitual sequence of codes:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But when the first code finishes, it appears the follow message:

```
W: Fail to search http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Fail to search http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

And appears some other messages too, but the site don't allow me to post more than 2 links with my reputation points.

I use the Ubuntu 15.04 vivid, Kernel Linux 3.19.0-15-generic, MATE 1.8.2.
I tried a sort of things, like update the `/etc/apt//sources.list`, and use the banish 404, but none of them was in success. If someone could help me, it would be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists/92897#92897), though if you could add the extra error output to your question that would help

Comment: Guidance is given by the answers in the duplicate question as to how to remove the PPA in question.  There are no packages for that PPA as per this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/92897/14356

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because it's actually so. The URL is currently unavailable.

Here, is a screenshot that says so:

[image: 1]

Also, as you can see the parent directory doesn't contain files for your ubuntu version. Screenshot:

[image: 2]

It is recommended to wait for a few hours untill the package is reuploaded to the website and then update your system to get the updates.

**EDIT:** As A. B. said, the application was never released for your version of Ubuntu. So, please remove the ppa or repository.

Comment: There was never a Vivid release.